# Why CSE formula doesn't work in NameManager, but works in cell?

Tags: excel

I'm so confused.Please tell me why CSE array formula works in cell,but doesn't work in NameManager?

All cells in range A1:A10 contains formula which in this case throws "" in A9 and A10. That's why I can't use `COUNTA(A1:A10)` to count not blanks, but I'm using `MIN(IF(A1:A10=""|ROW(A1:A10)))-1`.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

When I try to define this dynamic range as named, copy-pasting the formula in C1 into NameManager's "Refers to:" , troubles begin. Sorry for my english > I hope pictures can explain me better.

[image: image3]

[image: image4]

PS: I also tried to use `=INDIRECT(C1)` instead 
 `=OFFSET(A1|0|0|MIN(IF(A1:A10=""|ROW(A1:A10)))-1|1)` ,but same result apears

Comment: Try to use absolute references for each cell in your name's formula

Comment: Thx for the replay Ricardo Diaz. I tried to use absolute references. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce any errors. What's the Excel error you get?

Comment: I want to use that named range "Name_test" for data validation list. I want that list to show only not blank cells in range A1:A10. When I use static reference for "Name_test" , and put it as source for my data validation list it works, but shows blanks too. Otherwise when I use dynamic reference for "Name_test", the list shows nothing. No error massages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$10,SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$10<>"")))
```

It'll skip the blanks which result is ""

Let me know if it works

Comment: Seems like the problem is somewhere else. I found that both yours and mine formulas work fine if I call the name of the range directly. The problem is that I call name range indirectly for data validation source. INDIRECT() works fine if the named range is static, but does not work if the named range is dynamic. Thx for your help Diaz.I appreciate it.

Comment: My whole question is incorect. It should be: Why you can't select dynamic named range indirectly (INDIRECT(cell_containing_name_of_dynamic_range)), as source for Data Validation List?